# Hibernate StatelessSession error

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Within a batch, I am using Hibernate's StatelessSession insert and update methods to add or update objects in database without considering any context.

However I noticed that for large datasets, it generally fails with this error :

> 2017-10-18 01:39:46,263 [main] ERROR o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch -
>   HHH000315: Exception executing batch [Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [1]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
>   org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [1]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
>           at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
>           at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatch.java:133)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:110)

Object are stored in a Set. When it reaches 100 elements, these elements are inserted in database :

```
for (TempBuyingConditionBO tempBO:pager) {
    contextStatelessSession.insert(tempBO);
    insertedElements++;
}
commitBatch();
```

commitBatch definition :

```
public void commitBatch() {
    try {
        contextTransaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (contextTransaction != null) {
            contextTransaction.rollback();
        }
        getLog().error(e.getMessage());
    }
    contextTransaction = contextStatelessSession.beginTransaction();
}
```

It fails randomly after inserting more than 3000 objects.

It does not look like a functional issue as data inserted is correct. I checked hibernate mapping and saw nothing that could explain this error.

Maybe is it necesary to kind of flush the object previously inserted or use a "stateful" session ?

Any idea ?

Comment: it comes when the query expects the value while executing some ddl operations 
to know more info Add show_sql property in hibernate configuration like  hibernate.show_sql to true. This will show you the SQL that is executed and causes the problem.
and add logs to that class to get better info regarding issue

Comment: Hi vishaal, I already added specific logs but they did not help me a lot as hibernate basically inserts data in table (which I already knew).

I just saw that it crashed on the first insert of a batch (stored int the pager Set described above)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a "stateful" session and benefit of hibernate's functionalities (context, caching, ...)